# Using setUp and tearDown in Selenium Tests

Tags: java, selenium, junit

When using Selenium RC, I am able to use setUp and tearDown in the Suite but when I attempt to use setUp or tearDown in an individual test (within a suite), it errors.

This works fine and runs just once when the suite starts:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    System.out.println("in suite setUp method");
}
```

This fails as soon as the individual test is reached:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("in test setUp method");
}
```

The println actually gets called but the next selenium command fails (irregardless of what the command is).

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace (the error message you are seeing even if it looks simple) AND the rest of the code (the entire test)... I am guessing you are not initializing something correctly or its not in the right place but I cannot tell from the code that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created and initialize selenium object? I would like to suggest you to use [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks) where you don't need to worry about setup/teardown and to have some ready to use functionality.